# Redirecting admin/??? to admin.php/??? with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's my htaccess file at the moment:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

ErrorDocument 404 /blog/404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ post.php/$1.html

RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
RewriteRule ^archives$ archives.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php

RewriteRule ^feed$ feed.php
```

At the moment if I go to `domain.com/blog/*.html`, it is redirecting (in the background) to `domain.com/blog/post.php/*`

I would like to almost copy this but I'm not sure about all this regular expression stuff.

I would like to be able to also go to `domain.com/blog/admin/*` and for it to redirect (in the background) to `domain.com/blog/admin.php?p=*`

If you guys could help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?admin/(.*)$ admin.php?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Will do the trick.

This is done very quickly and it isn't tested but it gives you the idea. You put this above:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ post.php/$1.html
```

Edit: Took out the rewritecond since I just realised it is useless

Edit: Added query string too since you are actually converting the _GET now.

Comment: Cheers dude! I couldn't for the life of me, figure this out! This is just what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

Add multiviews to the first line of your .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Then, restart apache. It should point admin to admin.php.

Note: Don't have multiple files in the same directory with the same name and different extension.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html

Comment: WHat if he has an `admin.html` page in that directory? He is not requesting by php as such Apache cannot know.

Comment: Why would he have an admin.php and admin.html file in the same directory?

Comment: The PHP backend and the view. Separation of logic and presentation, bad separation but still separation.

Comment: I mean lets take an admin.png as well. Same concept same problem

Comment: Let's hope OP isn't doing such a thing. I'm willing to bet he has images, views, models, controllers, etc. directories. If not, he has bigger fish to fry than worrying about content negotiation.

Comment: Thanks, but is there anyway to only apply this to php files? :)

Comment: No. Multiviews will try to find the file/dir that best suits the url. The disadvantage to the other answer is that you're going to have to write a rule for all files you want to do this to. If you separate file names and types into directories ( url.com/images. url.com/js, url.com/css, etc.) then multiviews will be much easier to maintain. If you keep multiple files in the same directory with the same name but with different extensions (ie url.com/admin.html, and url.com/admin.php), then go with custom rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and help. I've got it setup exactly how I would like. I appreciate it guys